# nutch crawling with solr, job failed for depth >= 2

Tags: nutch

I am trying to run Nutch crawler on my local machine and want to index the retrieved data using solr.
Using apache-nutch-1.9 and solr-4.10.1

As of now they are installed and seem to run for depth = 1.

I get the following error when depth = 2

```
bin/crawl urls/ crawl http://localhost:8983/solr 2
```

.....

```
Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1357)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:114)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:186)
```

Comment: The error does not provide any useful information. Please post content from logs/hadoop.log. It contains more useful information than the standard command line message.

Comment: Turns out the steps in the following worked .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617141/solr-indexing-following-a-nutch-crawl-fails-reports-job-failed